# REGEX_EXTRACT in Data Studio not matching Regex pattern

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I am using REGEX pattern `-\\s.+?_{1}`
To match FY22_1-103_Evergreen **- US Territories (US Virgin Islands)_** Quitters_Video Views_Twitter Feed_07.01.21-09.15.21

But the results are null in the table the regex function is returning to. I'm not sure if I just don't fully understand the limitations of re2, or if I am missing something else.

EDIT:

I ended up trying a raw string `R"(-\s.+?_{1})"` which worked.

Comment: Try plugging in your regex at https://regex101.com/   It gives a good explanation of what your regex does, and there is a link there to run a Debugger on your test text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with a capturing group like

```sql
-\s+([^_]+)_
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBSAM1/1).

*Details*:

- `-` - a hyphen
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `([^_]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more chars other than an underscore
- `_` - an underscore.

Comment: So this worked perfectly in that it did not include "-" and "_" in the result. I wanted that but was expecting to have to remove them post regex extract. why is that?

Comment: @GarrettBaerg The regex extract function only returns the *captured* substring.